Asus TP500LA screen flipping issues
A little while ago i manages to pick up a Asus TP500LA off the side of the road and installed Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS onto it. works great but the screen doesn't flip when rotated 360 degrees.
what i have discovered is that when the screen does flip Ubuntu treats it as a switch that is pressed on and off each time its flipped either way and i wrote a little script to to solve that on a keyboard shortcut when what ubuntu calls Launcher2 is pressed
the issue is that only works if the laptop is powered on in the same state that the laptop is powered off in. anyone have any ideas on how to check what state the laptop is in?
value=`cat config.txt`
echo "$value"
if [ $value -eq "0" ]
    then
    echo inverting
    xrandr -o inverted
    echo "1" > config.txt
    else
    echo normalisin
    xrandr -o normal
    echo "0" > config.txt
fi ```



Can you please clarify what's the problem? Looking at the script it seems like it should work, the value will always be either 0 or 1, and the appropriate action will take place depending on the value. What's wrong with this behavior? Do you want the script to automatically figure out if the screen is fully opened / fully closed on its own?

so if the laptop is turned on with the screen flipped it will be upside down, i was wondering if anyone knew a way to resolve that
